# Why won't Internet Explorer 9 react to this click event? [short jsFiddle code inside]

Tags: javascript, dom-events, internet-explorer-9

Problem solved. Solution below.

It's been long since I tried to do this in pure javascript without jquery, but take a look:
http://jsfiddle.net/agilius/mKmTA/2/

It's a simple select list where double clicking an item moves it to the destination list. I wrote a bind function that detects if the object has `addEventListener` or `attachEvent`. jQuery does the same thing here https://github.com/robflaherty/jquery-annotated-source/blob/master/jquery-1.6.2/07-event.js#L118

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/agilius/mKmTA/ shows the modified working version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet Explorer doesn't think that "click" events happen on `<option>` elements.  Instead, they fire on the parent `<select>`.

Also of course @SLaks noted the bug in the event handler "bind()" function.

*edit* — another problem you may have is that `this` won't be set for you in IE (I think; it's not in IE8 anyway).

Comment: I was thinking about capturing the click on the parent tag, I'll update the code shortly.

Comment: Another note: in IE, you have to use "event.srcElement" to get the targetted element, not "event.target".  It'll be the `<select>` however, not the `<option>`.

Comment: I managed to make it work in IE with sourceElement.selectedIndex and sourceElements.childNodes[index]. There is a problem now where the clicking does not work every time. I'll update the question soon with the working version.

Comment: sourceList.options[sourceList.selectedIndex] gave me the item that was being double clicked. It works everywhere. IE7~8 need 3~4 clicks to work, but that's ok from my point of view.

Answer (score 2):

You're checking for `target.addEventListener` rather than `target.attachEvent` in the second `if`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/mKmTA/4/ (Of course, I'm not sure how well jsfiddle works with IE in the first place.)

Comment: thank you for pointing that one out Slaks :) but like Jared says, it still doesn't work in IE :|